# Which event loop should I use in Swift NIO?

Tags: swift, swift-nio

The [example](https://apple.github.io/swift-nio/docs/current/NIO/Classes/EventLoopFuture.html) in the docs shows an existing reference to the EventLoop for use with creating a future.

```
func getNetworkData(args) -> EventLoopFuture<NetworkResponse> {
    let promise = eventLoop.makePromise(of: NetworkResponse.self)
    queue.async {
        . . . do some work . . .
        promise.succeed(response)
        . . . if it fails, instead . . .
        promise.fail(error)
    }
    return promise.futureResult
}
```

In my case, I don't have access to the current EventLoop. Is there an easy way to get access to it?

Alternatively, I have access to an EventLoopGroup and I can use `services.lambda.client.eventLoopGroup.next()` to get an EventLoop. Does that just create extra overhead though? Should I be looking for an existing EventLoop?

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of questions in your question. So I'll answer what I consider the main question:

*I don't have access to the current EventLoop. Is there an easy way to get access to it?*

You initialize an EventLoopGroup as follows, you only need one per application. Also, depending on your usage you may typically only use 1 thread in *numberOfThreads* or for heavy usage, go with *System.coreCount* and it will use all available cores.

```swift
import NIO

let eventGroup = MultiThreadedEventLoopGroup(numberOfThreads: System.coreCount)
```

At that point *.next()* yields an eventLoop for you to use and when your future is complete, it returns for shared re-use.

At the end of your application, you shutdown as follows:

```swift
try eventGroup.syncShutdownGracefully()
```

A few notes about this:

1. If you are using a framework, such as *Vapor*, the framework already setup the eventGroup for you. Use their own, they do the setup and shutdown for you.
2. You mention *services.lambda.client.eventLoopGroup.next()*, so you may be using AWS Lambda? I'm not familiar with it, but if they provide an loop group, as in point 1, use that instead.